# Using Columnal and the 6th line of code gives an error, can this be fixed?

Tags: html, responsive-design, columnal-css-framework

```
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en-us" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

I've never come across something like this, but it looks a bit odd.. I'm used to seeing it more in this format (the previous line in Columnal):

```
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en-us" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
```

Firstly, what does the first code sample do? And do I need to worry about the format of it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first basically says: if the browser is greater than IE 9 or not an IE browser, that snipper of code will be used.

I have never seen such formatting before though.

- For downlevel-hidden one should use `<!--[if expression]> HTML <![endif]-->`
- For downlevel-revealed this one: `<![if expression]> HTML <![endif]>`

For more on this, check Microsoft's ['About'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).